# nothing provides httpd-mmn = 20051115 needed by php56w-5.6.33-1.w6.x86_64

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He googleado como no tienen idea... hasta el momento no he podido resolver este error, nuevo para mi; cualquier aporte  desde ya muchas gracias ! El error se presenta al momento de instalar php56w con el repositorio webtatic.

Comment: ya trataste con esta respuesta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154245/cant-install-php-package-on-centos?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa